# Custom MKAnnotationView Callout

Tags: iphone, android-mapview, mkpinannotationview

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Custom MKPinAnnotation callout bubble similar to default callout bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537259/custom-mkpinannotation-callout-bubble-similar-to-default-callout-bubble)
>   [How to customize the callout bubble for MKAnnotationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview/1769862#1769862)

Does anyone know, or have code that shows, how to create a custom MKAnnotationView Callout? I mean the actual text bubble and not the pin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

you cannot make a custom MKAnnotationView, you can only custom the callout views left and right, it's just a view, so you can put anything you want.
If you want a custom MKAnnotationView you will need to capture the touch and handle the rest.

Comment: I think my programmer did exactly that. Yes you can. Let me check the code.