# MKMapView Zoom to Annotations - annotationVisibleRect

Tags: mkmapview

Does anyone have an example of how to zoom an MKMapView to the area of all visible annotations **using the annotationVisibleRect property** on MKMapView?  I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680649/1072068) which offers a decent solution, but it seems that this annotationVisibleRect property would be the simplest solution.

Comment: The second answer in the linked post has what you're looking for.  But it doesn't make a difference whether you set region or visibleMapRect.

Comment: It doesn't address how to use the annotationVisibleRect property though.  That is really what I am looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short answer:** There is not a solution to this problem using `annotationVisibleRect`.

There is no example because this property cannot be used in this way. The limited documentation provided for it is certainly misleading for someone who is looking for something convenient from MapKit to do a somewhat common task.

`annotationVisibleRect` is the rect with regard to the `MKAnnotationContainerView` coordinate system. `MKAnnotationContainerView` is the superview for your annotations. If you look in MKMapView.h, you'll find this:

```c
// annotationVisibleRect is the visible rect where the annotations views are currently displayed.
// The delegate can use annotationVisibleRect when animating the adding of the annotations views in mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGRect annotationVisibleRect;
```

Its specific purpose is for manipulation (animation) of the annotation views by providing a rectangle in their superview's coordinate system that matches the map view's viewport.

You might think (as I did) that this or similar will do the trick:

```c
CGRect visibleRect = self.mapView.annotationVisibleRect;
MKCoordinateRegion visibleRegion = [self.mapView convertRect:visibleRect toRegionFromView:self.mapView];
[self.mapView setRegion:visibleRegion animated:YES];
```

It won't. Calling `setRegion:animated:` *may* cause the application to crash because the "fromView" is the incorrect coordinate system and may cause the latitude or longitude to go over their min/max values. You'd actually have to do something like this:

```c
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    if(views.count > 0) {
        MKAnnotationView *view = [views objectAtIndex:0];
        CGRect visibleRect = self.mapView.annotationVisibleRect;
        MKCoordinateRegion visibleRegion = [self.mapView convertRect:visibleRect toRegionFromView:view.superview];
        [self.mapView setRegion:visibleRegion animated:YES];
    }
}
```

This won't crash the application, but it won't change the region either. If you compare `visibleRegion` to `self.mapView.region`, you will find that they are identical. That is because the `annotationVisibleRect` represents the same area that is visible in the map view -- just in a different coordinate system to make it convenient for you to do things like make the map pins come flying in from the edge of the view. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139345/1370734) for details on how it is used.

Also, for reference, here's where the `MKAnnotationView` sits in relation to `MKMapView`:

```c
MKMapView
+-UIView
  +-MKScrollContainerView
    +-MKAnnotationContainerView    <-- coordinate system of annotationVisibleRect
      +-MKAnnotationView
```

Hope that helps clear some things up -- if not, ask away.

Comment: Thanks for the heavily detailed response.  I have long since left this code in the dust, but your explanation helps a lot.  If I get back to that code, I will make sure to reference your post.

Comment: np, I looked for a while to find the answer, so I'm sure others will stumble through here at some point.

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT 4

I think what your looking for is

```
mapView.showAnnotations(annotations:[MKAnnotation], animated: Bool)
```

You simply pass in an array of all the annotations you're trying to show which is the `MKMapView.annotations`

```
mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
```