# Custom pin animation - MKMapView

Tags: iphone

I have used pin images in application instead of standard pin, now i want to give animation (dropping effect as it was with standard pins) to custom pins. How can i provide dropping animation effect to custom pin images????

Comment: [This should help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857160/how-can-i-create-a-custom-pin-drop-animation-using-mkannotationview)

Answer (score 24):

Implement the following delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views { 
   MKAnnotationView *aV; 
   for (aV in views) {
     CGRect endFrame = aV.frame;

     aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y - 230.0, aV.frame.size.width, aV.frame.size.height);

     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.45];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
         [aV setFrame:endFrame];
     [UIView commitAnimations];

   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It feels also a lot cooler if you do not drop all the pins at once but drop each of them with a small delay so that it will look like there is a rain of pins effect. Similar to what Apple does natively. Use this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views { 
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 

    float delay = 0.00;

    for (aV in views) {
        CGRect endFrame = aV.frame;

        aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y - 430.0, aV.frame.size.width, aV.frame.size.height);
        delay = delay + 0.01;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:delay];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.45];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [aV setFrame:endFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me.  Cant remember where i found it on here though

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
MKAnnotationView *aV; 

for (aV in views) {

    // Don't pin drop if annotation is user location
    if ([aV.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        continue;
    }

    // Check if current annotation is inside visible map rect, else go to next one
    MKMapPoint point =  MKMapPointForCoordinate(aV.annotation.coordinate);
    if (!MKMapRectContainsPoint(self.mapView.visibleMapRect, point)) {
        continue;
    }

    CGRect endFrame = aV.frame;

    // Move annotation out of view
    aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x, aV.frame.origin.y - self.view.frame.size.height, aV.frame.size.width, aV.frame.size.height);

    // Animate drop
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.03*[views indexOfObject:aV] options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear animations:^{

        aV.frame = endFrame;

        // Animate squash
    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.05 animations:^{
                aV.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.8);

            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                if (finished) {
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
                        aV.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                    }];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that animating the annotation view in `-mapView:didAddAnnotationViews:` causes strange effects when `MKMapView.userTrackingMode` equals `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading`. I just wish Apple made the drop animation available to the `MKAnnotationView` class.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** drop animation

```
// animate annotation views drop
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didAdd views: [MKAnnotationView]) {
        for annView in views {

            // animate any annotation views except the user pin
            if !(annView.annotation?.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self))! {
                let endFrame = annView.frame
                annView.frame = endFrame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -500)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    annView.frame = endFrame
                })
            }
        }
```