# Why is my MKPointAnnotation not Custom?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapviewdelegate

My MKPointAnnotation should with this code be custom:

```
-(MKPointAnnotation*)setAnnotation: (NSString*) title atLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)Location withImage:(UIImage*) LocationImage{
    Pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    Pin.title = title;
    [Pin setCoordinate:Location];
    [self mapView:mapView viewForAnnotation:Pin].annotation = Pin;
    return Pin;
}



-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView: (MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation: (id<MKAnnotation>) annotation{

        MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];


        if(!pinView){
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.enabled = YES;
            UIButton *PicButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [PicButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showLocationPicture) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];\
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = PicButton;
        }
        else{
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
    return pinView;
}
```

Yet, for some reason, the Pin is still default, can anyone help me out here?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You shouldn't call `viewForAnnotation` yourself. You should only add annotations to your map view, which will then determine which are visible at any given moment and call `viewForAnnotation` for you. Thus:

- Given that different annotations can have different images, you really want to subclass `MKPointAnnotation` and give it a property of the `imageName` (note, not the `UIImage` itself, but a name or identifier that `viewForAnnotation` will be able to use to create the `UIImage` itself):

  ```
  @interface MyAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation
  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageName;
  @end

  @implementation MyAnnotation
  @end
  ```
- Add an annotation (not an annotation view) to your mapview, e.g.:

  ```
  - (id<annotation>)addAnnotationWithTitle:(NSString *)title coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate imageName:(NSString *)imageName
  {
      MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
      annotation.title = title;
      annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
      annotation.imageName = imageName;
      [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
      return annotation;
  }
  ```

  Note, I wouldn't suggest making `Pin` a class ivar/property, and I'd use camelCase for variable names (start with lowercase), I'd change the method name from `setAnnotation` to something like `addAnnotationWithTitle`, etc.
- Make sure your controller has been specified as the delegate of the mapView;
- The `viewForAnnotation` will be called for you (if the annotation is visible). It should probably be something like:

  ```
  - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
  {
      if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
          return nil;

      if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]])
      {
          MyAnnotation *customAnnotation = annotation;

          static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"MyAnnotation";
          MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
          if (!annotationView)
          {
              annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];
              annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
              annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
          }
          else
          {
              annotationView.annotation = annotation;
          }

          annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:customAnnotation.imageName];

          return annotationView;
      }

      return nil;
  }
  ```

  Note, the `animatesDrop` is a `MKPinAnnotationView` option that you can't do with custom annotation views. But it's easy to implement one if you want it (see [How can I create a custom "pin-drop" animation using MKAnnotationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857160/how-can-i-create-a-custom-pin-drop-animation-using-mkannotationview/7045916#7045916)). I'd suggest you tackle the basic annotation view first, and then look at custom annotation view drop animation later.

Comment: But how do I adjust the settings for the annotation then? because right now I use things like: pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = PicButton; but that doesn't work either

Comment: @BlackMagic See my revised answer with more complete code sample.