# Change Annotation Pin custom image in my MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am new. I would like to change my Pin images in my mapview.
How can change the image of the annotation?
I am sure I am missing something here.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier= @"myAnnotation";

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPin class]]) {
        MKAnnotationView *view =
        [self.mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        {
            view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            view.enabled =YES;
            view.canShowCallout =YES;
            view.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagePin.png"];

        }
                return  view;

        }
    return  nil;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my MKPointAnnotation not Custom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507171/why-is-my-mkpointannotation-not-custom)

Comment: may be something else