# Change pin image on MKMapView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to change pin image on the MKMapView in Swift, but unfortunately it don't work. Any Idea what I am doing wrong ? I saw some examples here, but did not worked.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class AlarmMapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showAlarms()
        map.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func showAlarms(){

        map.region.center.latitude = 49
        map.region.center.longitude = 12
        map.region.span.latitudeDelta = 1
        map.region.span.longitudeDelta = 1

        for alarm in Alarms.sharedInstance.alarms {

            let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                latitude: Double(alarm.latitude),
                longitude: Double(alarm.longtitude)
            )

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.setCoordinate(location)
            annotation.title = alarm.name
            annotation.subtitle = alarm.description
            mapView(map, viewForAnnotation: annotation).annotation = annotation
            map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func zoomIn(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    @IBAction func changeMapType(sender: AnyObject) {
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
        viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
            pinView!.image = UIImage(named:"GreenDot")!

        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
    }
}
```

GreenDot picture is available and used on other places.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't forget to set:

```
map.delegate = self
```

And make sure your `UIViewController` implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.
If you forget to do this, your implementation of `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` won't be invoked for your map.

Besides, it looks like `pinView!.animatesDrop = true` breaks custom images. You'd have to set it to `false`, or use `MKAnnotationView` (which doesn't have an `animatesDrop` property).

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857160/how-can-i-create-a-custom-pin-drop-animation-using-mkannotationview/2087253#2087253) if you want to implement a custom drop animation.

Comment: Ok I did this, now I can change pinColor with pinView!.pinColor = .Green , but when I try to change image with pinView!.image = UIImage(named:"GrayDot")!  this still don't works..

Comment: Have you tried using `MKAnnotationView` instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`?

Comment: Right I just did it with MKAnnotationView

Comment: Great! I've updated my answer with a few more details.

Answer (score 9):

MKPinAnnotationView always use a pin image, can't be everride. You must use MKAnnotationView instead.
Be aware because property animatesDrop it's not a valid MKAnnotationView's property, Rem the line.