# Adding Image to the MKAnnotationViewClass (Changing Annotation Pin)

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, xcode7, mkpointannotation

I've currently looked through the few tutorials on how to change the pin for the annotation. But all I've came across was nothing but errors within xcode 7 (Mainly all the breakpoints and it not working correctly). What I'm trying to do is use a Cloud that I have in my assets folder, and have that replace the normal Annotation. From the guides i've seen people are just using png files in which i'm not exactly sure where they should be located? But nonetheless any suggestions to the code that would allow me to replace it?

Cheers and Thanks

Heres my code

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
    longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 1.0
    longPressRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


func handleLongPress(getstureRecognizer : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if getstureRecognizer.state != .Began { return }

    let touchPoint = getstureRecognizer.locationInView(self.mapView)
    let touchMapCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)


}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span:  MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "Cloud"

    var CloudAnnotation = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if CloudAnnotation == nil {
        CloudAnnotation = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        CloudAnnotation!.image = UIImage(named:"cloud.png")
        CloudAnnotation!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        CloudAnnotation!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return CloudAnnotation
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}
```

and for the MKAnnotationViewClass

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var pinCustomImageName:String!
}
```

Previous threads that I looked at for information

[Change pin image on MKMapView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116571/change-pin-image-on-mkmapview-in-swift)

[Swift different images for Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKPointAnnotation {

        let identifier = "stopAnnotation"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
        if pinView == nil {
            //println("Pinview was nil")

            //Create a plain MKAnnotationView if using a custom image... 
            pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView.image = UIImage(named: "stopIcon")
        }
        else {
            //Unrelated to the image problem but...
            //Update the annotation reference if re-using a view...
            pinView.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView          
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: the if annotation is StopAction doesn't fit within the code :(

Comment: It got it to load but when I go to add the annotation by holding down for a couple seconds it causes a breakpoint at the func you recommended.

Comment: on which line, and what is the exception?

Comment: Fixed it, so now the thing I wasn't getting from the other guides was how to replace the annotation with an image.

Comment: solved half of it, just need to figure out how you Change the annotation pin

Comment: change image name which you want to set as pin. Please make sure that image is png.

Comment: Just for clarification if you set for example Annotation.png where would xcode grab the file from? The media assets folder?

Comment: Just add an image in image assets and set name of that image in code

Comment: Still not working, after i tried to use the image name