# Custom user picture for default User Location's callout on MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview, mkannotation

On **iOS 15** (actually since iOS 14), on a `MKMapView` when tapping on the default User Location a callout is shown displaying kind of an 'empty' profile picture.

You can see on the screenshot below the callout that appears when tapping the user location, I want to change the image that appears there.

[image: A map view showing the user location's callout]

Is it possible to configure it?

For example setting my own profile picture but the behaviour staying the same.

To clarify, I don't want to change the User Location annotation and I don't want to add a custom annotation either, also I don't want to add my own callout to the User Location's annotation. I just want to find out if it is possible to set an image for the existing callout.

The User Location shown on the picture is the default one using: `MKMapView.showsUserLocation = true`

---

### Edit

Some folks have pointed out that this might be a duplicated of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116571/change-pin-image-on-mkmapview-in-swift), it is not.

That other question deals with how to configure a Pin or Annotation View (`MKPinAnnotationView` or `MKAnnotationView`).

My situation is quite different. I want to be able to edit the profile picture shown on the default user location. This one seems to be a private class but I would like to know if there is a public access to configure it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change pin image on MKMapView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116571/change-pin-image-on-mkmapview-in-swift)

Comment: @teja_D it doesn't. As mentioned on the question I want to change the image on the User Location. I don't want to add a new pin to the map.

Comment: Did someone find an answer to this!!?, because Apple Maps is able to set my profile icon on that