# code for UICalloutView in iphone

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me the example code for UICalloutView in iphone.

Comment: there is no such class in cocoa-touch. Can you revise your question?

Comment: actually i saw this from http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UICalloutView but it's not working. it works like a dialog box .

Comment: You can't use that, it's not a public class. What are you actually trying to do? This view is used by the system when displaying maps. Basically when you tap on a point on the map (an annotation) this view is created, but you can't use it directly.

Comment: actually i want to display a dialog box or popup menu on the click.

Comment: If you're using a map, look at MKAnnotation (which is where the callout view gets its data from in general), if you're talking about a general dialog box, see UIAlertView and UIActionSheet

Answer (score 0):

There is default callout in mapView. If you want to customize it, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350050/custom-mkannotationview-callout)