# A cut out on a graph? How to? within a UIView, not mapKit

Tags: ios, swift, graph, graphics, core-graphics

IOS 11.x Swift 4.0

A caption popup on a graph line? How do they do this [It is from a fitbit app]? Is it a custom UIView or does someone know of an API/Kit that would make this easier?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Callout Bubble iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110423/custom-callout-bubble-ios)

Comment: There are several frameworks that provide "callout" functionality, just look here for example: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=callout+

Comment: These all seem to apply to the mapKit framework, with a reference to a private method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744073/code-for-uicalloutview-in-iphone?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa @ one point. Looking to do this in a vanilla UIView?

Comment: You could use a `UIPopoverPresentationController`

Comment: Andreas, I think I found the answer. Here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066623/customise-ios8-callout-bubble-swift?rq=1 need to try/test it.